# Shmiras halashon torah thought

Tags: halacha, torah-study

I would like to know a short torah thought by any of the Rebbes of Chabad speaking about the importance of shmiras halashon.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/5660169/jewish/Tazria-Where-Speech-Leads-a-Person.htm

Comment: A shorter synopsis: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/likkutei-sichos-parshas-metzora-tzaras-a-skin-lesion-preserved-for-the-righteous-which-reveals-the-hidden-impurity/